# $\phi_a:G^{A} \to G$ show $\phi_a(f)=f(a)$ is a homomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Assume $A$ is a set, $(G,*)$ is a group and and $a \in A$ Show the function

$\phi_a:G^{A} \to G$ defined by $\phi_a(f)=f(a)$is a homomorphism.

$G^{A}$ is the set of all functions from $A$ to $G$

let $f,g \in G^{A}$ and $ a_i \in A, i \in \mathbb{N} $

so $\phi_a(f) = f(a_1)$ and $\phi_a(g)=g(a_2)$

now,

$ \phi_a(f*g) = f(a_1) * g(a_2) = \phi_a(f) * \phi_a(g)$

I don't think I am showing it correctly

Comment: If you want to show $\;\phi_a\;$ is a *homomorphism* then you must provide $\;G^A\;$ with a structure of group, not only **set** . How will you do this?

Comment: associativity:
$f,g,h \in G^{A}$ we have $\Bigg(f*(g*h)\Bigg)(a) = f(a)*(g*h)(a)=f(a)*g(a)*h(a)=(f*g)(a)*h(a)=\Bigg((f*g)*h\Bigg)(a)$

Comment: You're using the same symbol * for the operation in $\;G\;$ and for the operation in $\;G^A\;$ . That is confusing, in the best of the cases, or simply wrong.

Comment: the problem states that the operation on $G^{A}$ and $G$  are both denoted by $*$ so I take it that its meant to be the same operation.

Comment: That seems to be a huge blunder, but what will I do?

Comment: yes I agree, it seems a bit weird. the identity would be some function $f_e$ that $(f_e*f)(a)=(f*f_e)=f(a)$ What can I show to show the identity exists though?

and similarly for the inverse $(f^{-1}*f)(a) = f_e(a)$

Comment: The identity in $\;G^A\;$ *has* to be $\;e(x)=1\;\;\;\forall\,x\in A\;$

Comment: ah because it's a product. then the inverse is $\displaystyle \frac{1}{f(a)} = f^{-1}(a)$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most probably $\;G^A\;$ is endowed with the product $\;(f\cdot h)(a):=f(a)h(a)\;,\;\;a\in A\;$ ,  and then

$$\phi_a(f\cdot g):=(f\cdot g)(a):=f(a)g(a)=\phi_a(f)\phi_a(g)$$

Comment: so I need a to be the same element for both functions f and h? And yes you are correct in assuming the product. on the previous problem it states $(f * g)(a)=f(a)*g(a)$

Comment: It's not that **I** need $\;a\;$ to be the same for both, but rather that is the way **you** defined $\;\phi_a\;$ !

Comment: thank you! $G^{A}$ is a group and $\phi_a(f) = f(a)$ is a homomorphism

Comment: I guess $G^A$ is ismorphic to the group $G\times G...\times G$ (|A| times).

Comment: I'll look in to that